# Weird high ping when another user on the same lan uses Skype

Tags: wireless-networking, lan, skype, ping

Well, this is not happening to me but my flatmate. He is having a high ping while playing(League of legends) as soon as I use skype (I've tested it by shutting it down and his ping was lowering subsequently).

So I'm kinda surprised, since I never experienced this problem before, and actually in my house (I'm sharing a flat now, so I'm referring when I was living with my parents few months ago) we used to have 4 pc and multiple android devices connected to the internet, and everything was fine (me and my brothers use Skype a lot) even when we firstly had a bandwidth of 20mb (same that what we have in here), now just 50mb of optical fiber, but doesn't really matter.

What I've tested so far, was setting our IP address to static so there won't be any chance of IP conflict, but it doesn't really help.

My guess so far is that somehow Skype is using the same port than LoL ? so there would be a bottleneck. If that's the problem I might be able to switch the ports on the router, but I just want to be sure about that.

Any other thoughts?

Comment: What is your upstream bandwidth?  The connection likely not 50/50,  Run speedtest.net for a quick check.

Comment: @Tyson For download is around 20mb as I said on my post and for upload is 0.74mb which is very crap for my taste, but don't see the problem since mostly upstreams are very low.

Comment: LoL and Skype with video will eat all of that .74mb upstream in a heartbeat, that is your bottleneck.

Comment: Check with your isp or internet provider.  First ask what your upstream speed should be now and see if you are getting what you pay for, and then ask what packages have more.

Comment: Ya well, i just rechecked and upstream is 1 mb, this mean that now that i have skype turned off (was talking when posting this),it becomes more. This mean that LoL (can) have the rest of it which is the enterely 0.70 mb and is more than enough for it (just googled). Im leaving the flat in few weeks so changing the ISP is not really an option.

Comment: I guarantee a 5mb up will solve the problem, 10 would be better.

Comment: @Tyson For uploads? That would be like 50mb of optical fiber or 100mb. So yea that would solve my problem but IMO would be like killing a fly with a cannon.

Comment: Been there done that... Your upstream speed is your bottleneck.  Both applications are streaming and it's getting saturated.  I pay for 100mb down just to get the upstream to 10mb.  I had 1mb for years because that's all they had in my area.

Comment: If your internet service is via ADSL2+, see if your modem supports Annex M, and see if your ISP can switch your service to Annex M. Annex M allocates more bandwidth to upstream than the typical default mode of ADSL2+ (Annex A) does.

Answer (score 0):

Try to uncheck

```
Use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections
```

in Skype Options/Connection.

Comment: I just did it, will test it tomorrow and if that worked i'll accept your answer, thanks for the reply.